# How do I write this program in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

How do I write every element in a list twice such that:

```
(double '(a((b)(c d)(((e)))))) --> '(a a((b b)(c c d d)(((e e)))))
```

I currently have this so far but it's not quite right.

```
(define double
  (lambda (x) 
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((list? x)(append (double (car x)) (double cdr x)))
          (else (cons x (cons x '()))))))
```

Comment: *every* element.. Wouldn't that amount to `(a a ((b b) (b b) (c c d d)(c c d d)(((e e)(e e))((e e)(e e)))(((e e)(e e))((e e)(e e))))((b b) (b b) (c c d d)(c c d d)(((e e)(e e))((e e)(e e)))(((e e)(e e))((e e)(e e)))))`?

Answer (score 1):

You were close to the answer, the key point is that we have to double the elements when the `car` of the list is an atom, not when the list itself is an atom, in this way we can modify the list that we're building as output. Here's a fixed version:

```
(define double
  (lambda (x) 
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((list? (car x)) ; ask about the car of the list. It's better to use pair?
           (cons (double (car x)) ; use cons, not append
                 (double (cdr x))))
          (else (cons (car x) (cons (car x) (double (cdr x)))))))) ; double the car
```

It works as expected:

```
(double '(a ((b) (c d) (((e))))))
=> '(a a ((b b) (c c d d) (((e e)))))
```